# What is the name of this fantasy game with cards and little treasure counters?

Tags: identify-this-game

I don't remember the name of this game I played with a friend many years ago (more than 15 years).

It had something to do with dragons and the game had each player draw cards and used round wooden tokens that I think represented your "hoard". I remember very clearly that there was one card that allowed my friend to "steal" from my hoard when I wasn't looking; which he did and admitted after the game (I still won!).

Does anyone know what this game is called?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've been googling around and finally found it. The game is called "Dragon's Gold" and was released in 2001 and re-released as a second edition (with some rule changes) in 2011.

Additional photos can be found here:

https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/1042/dragons-gold

Here is the box art of the game I played (first edition):

[image: box art for first edition]

Comment: I also want to mention that only this first edition had the small wooden tokens. The later editions replaced them with little plastic ones that resemble gems. I happened to prefer the original wooden ones which only came in the box pictured with this answer.